# Bootstrap markdown additionalButtons can't work with font awesome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, font-awesome

I'm using Bootstrap markdown js. I'm trying to add new buttons, everything it's ok, everything works, except it won't display icon if I'm using font awesome.

Here is my code:

```
$("#html_value").markdown({
            iconlibrary : 'fa',
            additionalButtons: [
                    [{
                    name: "groupCustom",
                    data: [{
                        name: "cmdBath",
                        toggle: true,
                        title: "Bath",
                        icon: "fa fa-facebook-square",
                        callback: function(e){
                            var chunk, cursor,
                                selected = e.getSelection(), 
                                content = e.getContent(),
                                chunk = "Wellness"
                                e.replaceSelection(chunk)
                                cursor = selected.start
                                e.setSelection(cursor,cursor+chunk.length)
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer:

```
$("#html_value").markdown({
            iconlibrary : 'fa',
            additionalButtons: [
                    [{
                    name: "groupBath",
                    data: [{
                        name: "cmdBath",
                        toggle: true,
                        title: "Bath",
                        icon: {
                            glyph: 'glyphicon glyphicon-link',
                            fa: 'fa fa-fire',
                            'fa-3': 'icon-link',
                            octicons: 'octicon octicon-link'
                        },
                        callback: function(e){
                            var chunk, cursor,
                                selected = e.getSelection(), 
                                content = e.getContent(),
                                chunk = "Wellness"
                                e.replaceSelection(chunk)
                                cursor = selected.start
                                e.setSelection(cursor,cursor+chunk.length)
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                ]
        });
```